# How can I start both TCP and UDP client in the same function concurrently?

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a UDP server-client system that works correctly. I want to create a single function that takes in input for both UDP and TCP connection sockets and these connections should be able to take input concurrently. Previously I worked with pthreads in C and I only know how to pass some tasks to specific functions(don't know how to do these tasks concurrently in the same function). Could you please provide a very simple example of a function that can run TCP client and UDP client concurrently?

```
void UDP(){
    int fd;
    if ( (fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket failed");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    memset( &serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr) );
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons( 50037 );              
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( 0x7f000001 );  

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        if (sendto( fd, "hello", 5, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0 ) {
            perror( "sendto failed" );
            break;
        }
        printf( "message sent\n" );
    }

    close( fd );
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>      // Default System Calls
#include <stdlib.h>     // Needed for OS X
#include <string.h>     // Needed for Strlen
#include <sys/socket.h> // Needed for socket creating and binding
#include <netinet/in.h> // Needed to use struct sockaddr_in
#include <time.h>       // To control the timeout mechanism
#include <unistd.h>
#define EXPR_SIZE   1024
#define BUFLEN      512
#define TRUE        1
#define SERVERLEN   1024
int main( void )
{
    int fd;
    if ( (fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror( "socket failed" );
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    memset( &serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr) );
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons( 50037 );
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );

    if ( bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0 ) {
        perror( "bind failed" );
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[200];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        int length = recvfrom( fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0, NULL, 0 );
        if ( length < 0 ) {
            perror( "recvfrom failed" );
            break;
        }
        buffer[length] = '\0';
        printf( "%d bytes: '%s'\n", length, buffer );
    }

    close( fd );
}
```

Comment: [Take a look at `select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). In *nix-land you can jam anything you can make look like a file into it. Handling many different sockets and types of sockets simultaneously is what it was designed for.

Comment: I did some research and this would work. But can you please give me an overview of how concurrent data receiving would work inside the function, keeping in mind that two data sources are not sending data at the same rate

Comment: `select` doesn't care bout the data rate. When one or more sockets has received data (or can be written to or did something "exceptional") it returns and tells you how many. You then go through the list of sockets you were selecting on and check with `FD_ISSET` to see if the socket is ready. In your case, you read the data from the socket. Beej gives good examples of a variety of different uses: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#cb57-32 . The gotchas are you want make the sockets non-blocking and you'll want separate input buffers for each socket read to read into.