# How to write a very simple TCP server-client system where client listens for 4 byte integer data?

Tags: c++, sockets

I extensively researched online and the examples of server-client systems on github are too complicated for me. What is the standard way of building a server-client TCP connection in cpp?

I built the UDP client-server with some help. Is there a way to modify these programs into a TCP client?

client

```
void UDP(){
    int fd;
    if ( (fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket failed");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    memset( &serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr) );
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons( 50037 );              
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( 0x7f000001 );  

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        if (sendto( fd, "hello", 5, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0 ) {
            perror( "sendto failed" );
            break;
        }
        printf( "message sent\n" );
    }

    close( fd );
}
```

server

```
int main( void )
{
    int fd;
    if ( (fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror( "socket failed" );
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    memset( &serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr) );
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons( 50037 );
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );

    if ( bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0 ) {
        perror( "bind failed" );
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[200];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        int length = recvfrom( fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0, NULL, 0 );
        if ( length < 0 ) {
            perror( "recvfrom failed" );
            break;
        }
        buffer[length] = '\0';
        printf( "%d bytes: '%s'\n", length, buffer );
    }

    close( fd );
}
```

Comment: _and the examples of server-client systems on github are too complicated for me._ What about [google "c++ TCP client tutorial"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+TCP+client+tutorial)? TCP communication isn't the most complicated I did but I wouldn't say it's easy-peasy. I guess if you've never done this before it cannot be mastered without digging a bit in.

Comment: FYI: [Yet another similar active question about TCP/UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61650510/7478597)

Comment: Sadly all the results from google that I checked are examples written in C. I do have a code that is working in C but C++ would be better

Comment: That is a UDP connection

Comment: The socket APIs (Windows as well as *nix) are C APIs. So, I wouldn't wonder if you found primarily C examples. However, they can be used in C++ as well. (In our project, I once wrote a C++ wrapper to make it re-usable for our purposes although it got a little bit aged meanwhile.) Boost probably provides at least one as well and there might be others also. (Though, I wouldn't consider Boost as non-complicated...) ;-)

Comment: _That is a UDP connection_ ??? What is a UDP connection?

Comment: Concerning TCP in C++: [google "c++ tcp socket wrapper"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+tcp+socket+wrapper)

Comment: TCP is inherently more complicated then UDP. You can't just "change UDP to TCP", these work differently. Embrace this difficulty and learn TCP properly. Also C socket api will work just fine with C++.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will work on it now :).